# restclient in emacs are not evaluation elisp

Tags: restclient

my .rest file have a variable

`:authKey = (getenv "GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN")`

My problem is that :authKey value is been evaluating as literal (getenv "GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN"). Elisp is not been evaulated.

What could be the problem my restclient mode is not avaluating elisp?

The request works fine when use :authKey 123 (hard coded key)

The major modes actives in my .rest file buffer is:

```
(ReST +2 Helm yas WK Abbrev Fill)
```

as showed below...

[image]

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a character. I’ll quote from the documentation:

```
You declare a variable like this:

:myvar = the value

or like this:

:myvar := (some (artbitrary 'elisp)
```

If you want it to evaluate it as elisp, you must use the `:=` assignment operator.

Normally questions like this should be posted to the package’s support forums, not the Emacs support forums. Since this package is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/pashky/restclient.el), you really should ask this type of question over there on GitHub.

Comment: Working now db48x thanks you